# How to force open URL in WebView? Set App as Default for WebView URL

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I am trying to open my WebView app from URLs from browser and Google Search.

I tried using the following code as suggested here: [How to launch app on click of url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807300/how-to-launch-app-on-click-of-url-in-android)

```
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.webviewurl.com"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

But it didn't work.

I want to force open all URLs like:

```
https://*.webviewurl.com/*
http://webviewurl.com/*
```

to `https://www.webviewurl.com/*` in the WebView.

I've already done this part in the server using `.htaccess`.

I want the URLs to open in WebView by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by doing the following:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.webviewurl.com"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class webclient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("play.google")){
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            if ((url.contains("webviewurl.com"))) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            } else {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Which is working fine. Only problem is, all the pages are opening the homepage in app.

Like if an user clicks on a link say `https://www.website.com/folder/page` from browser, it opens `https://www.website.com/` in the app.

How do I fix this issue?