# Start native Application from Tile in Fiori Launchpad?

Tags: sapui5

is it possible to start a native App on the device from the Fiori Launchpad?
I would like to create a Tile that navigates the user to the native app on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Android.

Step 1. Ensure that your app opens with an URL. Say `appname://screen` . Refer [How to launch app on click of url in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807300/how-to-launch-app-on-click-of-url-in-android)

Step 2. In the Fiori Launchpad Tile Configuration, do not use "semantic object navigation. Instead, enter "Target URL" as `appname://screen`.